# Setting a column default value in the kendo ui grid to DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I wish to make a grid within my visual studio program to display DateTime.now as a default but it's not working.

The column within the Kendo grid:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.CurrentDate).EditorTemplateName("Date").Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}");
```

The declaration within my model:

```
public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
```

When I load the web page the value of the text box within the column is set to the current date but the value is not displayed.

**My Kendo UI Grid Code:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.Models.EID>()
        .Name("EIDGrid")
        .Columns(
            columns =>
            {

                columns.Bound(c => c.Breed);
                columns.Bound(c => c.Gender);
                columns.Bound(c => c.AnimalId);
                columns.Bound(c => c.EIDDate).EditorTemplateName("Date").ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy"));//.ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString()).Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}").EditorTemplateName("Date");//.EditorTemplateName("Date")
                columns.Bound(c => c.EIDNum);
                columns.Bound(c => c.BatchNum);
            }
    )
    .Scrollable(s => s.Height("350px"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.SireGuid);
            //model.Field(p => p.SireGuid).DefaultValue(Guid.Empty);
            //model.Id(p => p.EIDDate);
            //model.Field(p => p.EIDDate).Editable(true);

        })
        .PageSize(100)
        .Batch(true)
        .Sort(s => s.Add("Name"))
    ) )
```

**My Model code:**

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Globalization; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;

namespace Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.Models {
   
    public class EID
    {

        public string Breed { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string AnimalId { get; set; }
        public int EIDNum { get; set; }
        public int BatchNum { get; set; }

        public DateTime EIDDate { get; set; }
        

        
       
        public int ClusterIndex
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public System.Guid SireGuid { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

**My Controller Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.Controllers {
    public class EidController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Eid
        public ActionResult EidView ()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not assign a default value to the `CurrentDate` auto property? e.g. `public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now`

Comment: Managed to get it working using columns.Bound(c => c.CurrentDate).ClientTemplate(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")); - but I cannot edit the date of the columns it display in, any idea why?

Comment: ClientTemplate method is designed to define look of your data - not data itself. To set default date uou have to define default property value in the model layer (as Sandman said) or modify your dataSource object in javascript when your data is bound.

Comment: public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now; makes the columns blank for me - sorry if what I ask seems stupid, I'm new to this

Comment: Could you provide more details how is your grid beeing defined? Maybe there is something wrong with mvc wrapper configuration?

Comment: <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.Models.EID>()

                        .Name("EIDGrid")

                        .Columns(
                            columns =>
                            {

                                columns.Bound(c => c.CurrentDate)
                                
Do you wish to see how the statements are closed? could not provide because of character limit.

Comment: Don't provide updates like this as a comment, update your question with any additional information requested/you feel is necessary to provide more context to your issue.

Comment: @GeorgeB - You should also show how is your model passed from controller to view. Instead posting code in comments - please edit your question for better clarity.

Comment: Ok I have added the information to the main part of the question, the CurrentDate has been changed to EIDDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

**Model:**

```
public class Eid
{
    public string Breed { get; set; }    
    public DateTime EIDDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string SireGuid { get; set; }
}
```

**MVC wrapper:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIApp3.Models.Eid>()
    .Name("EIDGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Breed);            
        columns.Bound(c => c.EIDDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yy}");            
    })
    .Scrollable(s => s.Height("350px"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .Pageable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.SireGuid);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("EIDRead", "Home"))
        .PageSize(100)
        .Batch(true)
        .Sort(s => s.Add("Breed"))
    ))
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EIDRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var collection = new List<Eid>()
        {
           new Eid
           {
               Breed = "test",
               SireGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
           }
        };

        return Json(collection.ToDataSourceResult(request));           
    }
```

You have to define a way your grid is populated by data. In this case I use .Read function to query controller method EIDRead for rows. Of course you can pass your data directly to the grid, but this method is much easier for maintainance.

Comment: I have just added only elements that correspond a solution. You must fill you controller class with everything you need. See method that returns view (EidView) is not included. Also notice .Read method in wrapper - you must provide a right controller. In my case it was "Home".

Comment: Ok got it working, why is there only 1 row in the table?

Comment: Because test collection that I provided has only one element.

Comment: So would I be able to link Breed to a database full of breeds?

Comment: To populate your grid with data from database you need to build a collection type that contains its data. At first fill collection with data and later pass it to your grid as my example shows.

Comment: Ok I will give that a go, thanks a lot for the help, am a novice at working with MVC, Kendo etc :)

Comment: Here is kendo mvc grid reference: [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid). Examples are well illustrated so I hope it will help you for further approaches.